# Get channel location information on YouTube API V3

Tags: youtube-api

Since YouTube has deprecated API V2, I cannot find a way to get the location or the region code of a channel. I used to use the  value found on V2 API
e.g GB.

The official documents suggest that this feature will NOT be moved to V3.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/deprecated#Channel_Location

Has anyone discovered a successful workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Channels don't have a location anymore, your best bet is to analyze uploaded videos' location and estimate.

Comment: You can only get a video's location if you're a the video owner.